# Does Ninject deactivate transitive dependencies when the underlying one deactivated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, ninject

I got the `IUnitOfWork` interface (with its implementation which I wont show you):

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ...
}
```

Note the `IDisposable` inheritance. Also, I got the service with the appropriate implementation:

```
public interface IBusinessLogicService
{
    ...
}

public sealed class BusinessLogicService : IBusinessLogicService
{
    // Dependency is auto-injected by ninject
    // because of the custom injection heuristic.
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

There we go the ninject binding:

```
kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IBusinessLogicService>().To<BusinessLogicService>();
```

As you can see, ninject will automatically deactivate the `IUnitOfWork` instance at the end of the request and also dispose it.

Now, the question,
will the ninject **also deactivate** (and reactivate on the next web request) the instances (like `IBusinessLogicService`) that **are dependent** on the deactivating object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Ninject will deactivate an object when the scope is collected **if there is a scope**. Transient objects are not tracked by Ninject and are considered to be managed externally [and fresh instances are created wherever one is required].

The deactivation point for a scope worth of objects [is normally dictated by when the scoping object gets garbage collected](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/).

For `InRequestScope` the deactivation takes place deterministically at the end of a request using an ASP.NET pipeline hook.

[See also `Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope`](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki) for more options in this space

Comment: Okay then, but will it somehow switch the reference to the underlying re-activated object?

Comment: No. Ninject does no magically internal replacements of object instances. You probably want to put your service InRequestScope(); too.

Comment: I probably will put ALL my services into that scope :/

Answer (score 0):

Ninject is only responsible for dependency injection. It will instantiate the interface variable with class instance depending on the kernel binding. It is not responsible for deactivating instances created using Ninject.
The deactivation of object will follow the normal asp.net framework's object destruction cycle.

Comment: Not strictly true except for Transient Scope. Can you expand your answer to explain how InRequestScope stuff works and that there is a Kernel.Release() or delete it please?